# how to get the weight unit of the product from quote in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2.2, quote, product-weight

I wish to get the weight unit of the product from quote in magento 2.
Please provide me a solution to get quote value.

Comment: Do you want total weight or individual product weights?

Comment: I got the weight from quote. I need weight unit like lbs,grams

Comment: You can't get it from quote, you need to get it from system config under Locale configuration.

Comment: Do you want the code how to achieve this?

Comment: I have achieved this @SukumarGorai,Thank you

Comment: Great Happy coding.